# Is passing a promise accept function in redux actions an anti pattern, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I sometimes have a GUI component that needs to know when an async action completes.  Basically I dispatch an action and I want a promise that yields when the process is completed.  From what I understand the component can't simply listen for actions from the store. Or can it?

I use redux-saga, but I think this is a general problem.

The way I do this now is to **create a promise and pass the accept/reject functions to the actions** - so that whatever handles it can resolve the promise for me. I then keep the promise and hope that the action are picked up and the methods called.  (I don't store the methods in state, just in the sagas processing the action.)

This seems fragile, and I wonder: **Is there any other way my component can receive an event when a process is completed**? I know I could use the *state for signaling*, but that sometimes seem too much scaffolding for this little thing.

*Edit*

One case I ran across is submitting of forms.  The (sagas) middleware will first run validation, which could also be async, then submit the form to the server. While this is going on, I don’t want the user to be able to click again or edit. This is what the promise helps ensure. As always, when writing up a problem to someone, i realize that a redux state flag would be better in this specific case - although somewhat elaborate.  However, I have more cases like this so my question stands.

Comment: *"The way I do this now is to create a promise and pass the accept/reject functions to the actions..."* Why that rather than have the *action* create the promise and give it to your code? Normally, the creation and settlement of the promise should be handled by the same thing. Creating the promise in X but settling it in Y feels wrong.

Comment: You are right, but when I use raw action methods and binds them in the react `connect` method I don't get a way to return a promise (?).  redux-thunk does return a promise, when used this way, but still doesn't allow us to wait for something like a saga to complete and raise a "done action".

Comment: This sounds confusing for me. Can you give an example? What is your scenario